# simple html dom loading different page than url

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to pull in a webpage with php's simple html dom parser and I'm having an odd problem with it. I am defining the url variable by concatenating two strings.

```
$itemUrl="http://www.example.com/";
$pageUrl="default.asp?pg=DispSingleItem&ItemNumber=1234";
$itemUrl .=$pageUrl;
$html=file_get_html($itemUrl);
```

When I run this script I end up going to a page that says "Item Not Found". However, when I echo the $itemUrl, copy the output, and paste it into the browser, I go directly to the page I am looking for. Also, if I just put the entire url saved as one string to begin with it, takes me to the correct webpage.

```
$itemUrl="http://www.example.com/default.asp?pg=DispSingleItem&ItemNumber=1234";
$html=file_get_html($itemUrl);
```

I have tried using urlencode on the concatenated string, but that doesn't help. I am really stumped. I can't think of a reason why the concatenated url would take me to a different page when the same url, copied directly and pasted into another variable, takes me to the correct page. What am I missing here? Any help would be great, thank you.

EDIT:
I found the issue. The echo of $pageUrl showed this:

```
default.asp?pg=DispSingleItem&ItemNumber=1234
```

When in reality the variable was saving a string that looked like this:

```
default.asp?pg=DispSingleItem&amp;ItemNumber=1234
```

My browser was automatically translating the & amp; to simply &, which looked like exactly what I needed. Whenever I ran file_get_html though, the string was not converted and so the script was trying to get it from a url that had & amp; not just &. I added:

```
$pageUrl=preg_replace("/amp;/", "", $pageUrl);
```

Does anyone know of a way to get a browser to output exactly what the variable is, without altering it like what happened in my problem? It would be useful to know in the future.

Thank you to all of the responses. I wasn't expecting so many or so quickly.

Comment: What is `file_get_html`? Is it like `file_get_contents`? Additionally, what cookies are you sending when viewing the page in your browser?

Comment: @arxanas Whatever `file_get_html` is, it doesn't explain the behaviour `michael tyler` is describing. In both cases the same URL is passed in (according to the code given at least). @`michael tyler`: Make sure error reporting is on. My hunch is you have a typo in a variable name somewhere in your original code and not in the examples you gave here.

Comment: @RobIII The cookies or other headers being sent might, which could arise from the usage of `file_get_html`.

Comment: Can you provide the full code? Please use real URLs.

Comment: @arxanas read the last paragraph of the question again.

Comment: @arxanas Agreed but that would mean that `file_get_html` would keep some global (and even persisted across requests/executions?) state resulting in 2 requests being made differently. This *might* be the case but a method should, for a given input, usally, result in the same output/behaviour (ignoring external data sources in this case).

Comment: What headers are produced by viewing the page in the browser, as opposed to [`get_headers`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php)?

Comment: @arxanas: file_get_html is part of simple_html_dom, and basically just does file_get_contents plus loads the results into the DOM parser automatically.

Comment: @RobIII I ran it with the error reporting turned on and did not receive any errors. Marc B is correct on how file_get_html works. Sorry, I should have included that information in the start.

Comment: @arxanas I'm not sure I understand why the headers would affect anything. In both cases I am sending the url through the script's file_get_html. I will check the headers now though and get back to you.

Comment: I don't happen to know the specifics of the website, but it could be that there are session variables required to render the page.

Answer (score 0):

Your last question was:

> Does anyone know of a way to get a browser to output exactly what the variable is, without altering it like what happened in my problem? It would be useful to know in the future.

If I understood it correctly, you would like to know about a way of preventing the browser of rendering a url string like `www.example.com?p=1&amp;e=2` as `www.example.com?php=1&e=2`.

A way of doing that is using `echo htmlentities($url);` instead of merely `echo $url;`. That way, the `&amp` part of the string would be rendered by the browser exactly as that.

Example code:

```
<?php
$url = "www.example.com?p=1&amp;e=2";
echo $url;
echo "<br/>";
echo htmlentities($url);
?>
```

Resulting browser output:

```
www.example.com?p=1&e=2
www.example.com?p=1&amp;e=2
```